# how to calculate the angle in GoogleVR sdk in unity 3d

Tags: android

the rotational tunnel in unity3d using googleVR sdk, I want to calculate the view angle of the central part(the circle with white and black color), and make sure when you using google cardboard your eye perceive the same angle

[image: enter link description here]

can I use this way to calculate the view angle, manually adjust the field of view of main camera to make the scene only include the central part of the tunnel(make the vertical line of camera preview frame tangent to the central part of the tunnel). just as the picture show, 12 degree is the view angle.

[image: enter link description here]

I don't have much knowledge about googleVR sdk. Thank you in advance!